# Why is Tomcat Maven Plugin failing to redeploy with error 404?

Tags: maven, tomcat, maven-plugin, maven-tomcat-plugin, tomcat-manager

A 404 error is occurring after trying to redeploy via Tomcat Maven plugin, which uses [Tomcat Manager](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html) to perform this action.
It was verified that the Manager application is not available at http://localhost:8080/manager.

**pom.xml:**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</plugin>
```

**Start server:**

```
mvn tomcat7:run
```

**Redeploy:**

```
mvn package tomcat7:redeploy
```

**Error:**

```
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:redeploy (default-cli) @ app ---
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/app
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fapp&update=true
Uploaded: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fapp&update=true (3950 KB at 3253.3 KB/sec)

[ERROR] Tomcat return http status error: 404, Reason Phrase: Not Found
```

Comment: In the tomcat make sure you have the manager web app deployed.

Comment: How to activate the Manager app via the Tomcat Maven Plugin configuration? The documentation doesn't explicitly mention it, so probably it should be activated by default.
http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/

Answer (score 0):

the reason is, missing the **manager**  in the war files installation path.

to fix, copy those files/folders from *TOMCAT_DIR/webapps* to the relevant war installation path.